# Start one pod at a time when replica is greater than one

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, orchestration

Is there a way to ensure that pods are scaled one at a time when setting replica greater than one?

Example: Replica set to 3

1. Pod 1 - Initializing , pod 2 - Waiting, pod 3 - Waiting
2. Pod 1 - Running , pod 2 - Initializing, pod 3 - Waiting
3. Pod 1 - Running , pod 2 - Running, pod 3 - Initializing
4. Pod 1 - Running , pod 2 - Running, pod 3 - Running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can acomplish this behavior using `StatefulSets`. As it goes from [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#deployment-and-scaling-guarantees)

> - For a StatefulSet with N replicas, when Pods are being deployed, they are created sequentially, in order from {0..N-1}.
> - When Pods are being deleted, they are terminated in reverse order, from {N-1..0}.
> - Before a scaling operation is applied to a Pod, all of its predecessors must be Running and Ready.
> - Before a Pod is terminated, all of its successors must be completely shutdown.

So, as you can see here, new pod is not booted up until previous one is initializing.

**Note:** this behavior is guranteed by Kubernetes when `OrderedReady` pod management policy is used (which is default).